# Wordpress: Get recent posts, exclude current post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get recent posts, only in the category of the current post, while excluding the current post, but I can't get it to work:

```
$curr_cat = get_the_category();

$args = array( 'numberposts' => '10', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'category' => $curr_cat['0']->cat_ID, 'exclude' => $post->ID );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
```

It's just showing the current post over and over again.

Comment: It's everything right with your code. How are you trying to output this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, be sure that you are echoing your posts like:

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
}
```

If you are doing like above, be sure that `$post` is set and you are in a category archive or single post file.

Answer (score 2):

John, you can try something like code below, I don't know your case but it works for me in one of my project

```
$args = array ('category__in' =>  $curr_cat['0']->cat_ID, 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) );
```